# How can I get gcc to treat field access in a switch like an array access?

Tags: c, gcc, optimization

For example, GCC 4.9.0 at `-O3` compiles this

```
typedef struct {
  double x, y, z;
} vector;

double
vector_get(const vector *v, size_t i)
{
  switch (i) {
  case 0:
    return v->x;
  case 1:
    return v->y;
  case 2:
    return v->z;

  default:
    __builtin_unreachable();
  }
}
```

to a comparison and jumps (bigger examples get a jump table).  But the optimal compilation is just

```
return ((double *)v)[i];
```

(if it were defined).  The obvious solution is to replace the separate `vector` fields with an array, but the ability to write `.x`, `.y`, etc. greatly improves readability in other parts of the code.

Comment: Hi, I'm a bit at a loss at to the constraints. Can the `vector` be replaced w/ a `union`? You could get a type-based call.

Comment: Is this actually meant as a serious question? To get gcc to do optimizations it doesn't do, volunteer to improve it ... it's open source.

Comment: @JayInNyc Is the `union` actually guaranteed to align `x`, `y`, and `z` with `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`?

Comment: No, the union will have a memory footprint of one double. Ok, that's clearly not your use case.

Comment: @JayInNyc I assumed you meant something like `union { vector v; double array[3]; }`

Comment: So, forgetting the union, just do your own pointer math on the vector. Simple.

Comment: "if it were defined" -- What do you mean? Your question specifically asks about gcc, not the C standard. The cast is certain to work with gcc.

Comment: @JayInNyc I'd like to avoid UB though... maybe there's a way to do it with `offsetof()`, I'll try that.

Comment: btw, -O3 on gcc is very very good -- do you doubt its optimization?

Comment: "the union will have a memory footprint of one double" -- uh, not if the union contains double[3]

Comment: @JimBalter I would like to write standard C that compiles to efficient machine code with GCC.

Comment: @JimBalter Obviously -- I never did suggest that.

Comment: @JimBalter: He probably refers to the fact that any conformant compiler can add an arbitrary amount of padding after each member, though I know none which adds any for the example.

Comment: "I would like to write standard C that compiles to efficient machine code with GCC" -- then we're back to my original comment.

Comment: @Deduplicator I know what he refers to, but his question is specifically about gcc. If he insists on standard-compliant code the question should say that ... but it's a foolish restriction when every extant compiler will work fine with the cast.

Comment: "maybe there's a way to do it with offsetof()" -- Sure, you could do it with an array of offsets, but a) it would be ugly and b) gcc is even less likely to optimize *that*.

Comment: @JimBalter You're right, gcc isn't smart enough to eliminate the access to the offset array.  But even with it it's only two instructions.

Comment: If you are expecting GCC to generate code to what you think is optimal, then whatever assumptions you are making in your head to think it should be able to do that should just be fair game in your code (but properly documented). So, use a union.

Comment: @jxh I would like the code to still *work* with other compilers (though I could obviously use an `#ifdef` for that).  I'd also like GCC to be unable to detect UB, so it won't delete the code entirely (for example).

Comment: If you are invalidating the assumptions that would make the "optimal" code a correct conversion of the original switch based code, then your question is not well-formed. Please note that while the standard is a little fuzzy about the layout of structures and interactions between different union members, the practical application of these constructs in working code is numerous. So if a compiler happened to do something a programmer didn't expect, most likely that compiler would just not get used anymore (since there are alternative compilers that "work").

Comment: @TavianBarnes If you could get around the code readability concerns by using an `enum{X,Y,Z}`; would you consider just using an array and accessing the elements like `v[X], v[Y], v[Z]`?

Comment: @technosaurus I don't really want to expose `X` in a library and `PREFIX_X` is a little ugly.  If I go that route I'll just bite the bullet and accept `[0]` etc.

Comment: You can get around some of the ugliness with a macro `#define VECTOR(v,x) PREFIX_VECTOR_##x(v,x)`

Answer (score 2):

That depends on how strictly you want to avoid undefined behavior.

Yes, the language standard does not guarantee that the doubles in your vector are placed right next to each other in memory, but no sane compiler will introduce padding. Since you also do not intend to access a double via an int pointer or similar evil things, you should not be in conflict with strict aliasing rules.

So, from a language lawyer point of view, the cast `((double*)v)[i]` is undefined behavior, but in practice, you are very likely to get away with it.

If you want to avoid the cast, you can also take the address of the first coordinate like this: `(&v->x)[i]`

If you want to abide by the language rules in a strict way, then you are out of luck. The compiler is allowed to add *any* amount of padding between the coordinates (no matter whether doing so is sane in any way), so accessing `y` or `z` through pointer arithmetic or by means of a `union` is undefined behavior. There is no way around this, not even by tricks with `memcpy()`.

---

If you go for the array access despite the fact that it is technically undefined behavior, you can at least safeguard against padding by asserting on the size of the struct:

```
_Static_assert(sizeof(vector) == 3*sizeof(double), "Your compiler inserts padding between doubles, but this code assumes that there is no such padding.");
```

However, this is still not bulletproof, because the UB always means that the optimizer is allowed to optimize your code away if it's smart enough to realize that it's UB.

Comment: accessing `x` is always good, because it is the first member, which must be at position 0, aka have the same address as its containing `struct`.

Comment: The OP suggests using offsetof. One could compliantly do so, but there's no reason to expect gcc to optimize that into a double index -- but you never know; there are **no** guarantees of what code a compiler will generate, even between compiles of the same code.

Comment: Technically it's ID whether it is UB.

Answer (score 2):

Your question is about gcc, but you seems to want compatibility with standard C as much as possible.

The standard C gives some knowledge about the allignment properties of struct members in a given struct variable. This allows to do some operations, like to calculate the offset between members in a struct. You need to know this offset to perform access in "pointer mode" to a "struct variable".

But, it seems that you want exactly the opposite: to access a "pointer or array" as if it were a "struct". This is not guaranted to work, because the struct could have padding bytes between two consecutive elements. But in an array it is guaranted that all contiguous elements are in memory without any padding.

My conclusion is that, in general, what you are trying to do will leave you to errors.
It is not impossible sintactically, but the problem is that the allignment of bytes depends on the compiler: it cannot be predicted.

We can say for sure that:

- An array of 3 elementos, of `doubles` to be concrete, holds in a block of contiguous bytes in storage space (memory) in 3 contiguous objects of type `double`.
- A struct of three elements `x,y,z` of type double holds in a block of contiguous bytes, following the order of member declaration. So `.x < .y < .z`.
- The bytes of a struct can be copied with `memcpy()` so, in particular, the relative address of these bytes can be accessed (by starting from the address of first byte of the struct).
- It could be padding bytes between contiguos elements. So, the address of `.y` is not necessarilly the address of the member `.x` "plus" `sizeof(double)`.
- The address of the first member of the struct coincides with the address of the struct itself. This means that there is not padding bytes at the beginning.
- It could there be padding bytes at the end of the struct.

The choice of padding bytes depends on the compiler.

So, type punning with a union is not guaranteed to give you the portable results that you expect.

Comment: @Deduplicator This answer says "could have padding bytes between two consecutive elements" which is true. There can also be padding after the last member, of course, but that isn't relevant to this particular question.

Comment: @Deduplicator: I mentioned the trailing padding just for completion. I know that is not relevant for the question.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yes, sometimes it is ... which is why I pedantically responded to you. Oh, and, the answer does say "It could there be padding bytes at the end of the struct."

Answer (score 2):

As you suggest, replace the three members with an array (or vector if you want). Then add inline access functions `x()`, `y()`, and `z()`, which return respectively, `v[0]`, `v[1]`, and `v[2]` (you could even return references to allow them as l-values.

Comment: This is C though, not C++.

Comment: Oops, sorry. Well in that case, use macros? (e.g., `#define X(v) (v[0])`

Comment: Yes this is where C++ wins out, encapsulate in setters/setters and back the implementation with an array, then its exactly what OP wanted.

Comment: Well, if you use the `define` approach, you should add all the necessary parentheses: `#define X(v) ((v)[0])`

Answer (score 0):

You can determine if your structure layout is amenable to your optimization in several ways, but one way is:

```
#define X_O offsetof(vector, x)
#define Y_O offsetof(vector, y)
#define Z_O offsetof(vector, z)

const int vector_is_packed
    = ((Z_O - Y_O) == (Y_O - X_O)) && ((Y_O - X_O) == sizeof(double));
```

Then, you can write your code as follows:

```
double
vector_get_0 (const vector *v, size_t i)
{
    if (vector_is_packed) {
        return *(double *)((char *)&v->x + i*sizeof(double));
    }

    static const size_t delta[] = {
        offsetof(vector, x), offsetof(vector, y), offsetof(vector, z)
    };
    return *(const double *)((const char *)v + delta[i]);
}
```

The dead code optimization will leave one path or the other, depending on whether the platform has packed the three doubles or not.

Comment: The OP tried that (see the comments under the question) ... gcc doesn't optimize away the memory access to the delta array.

Comment: Also there's really no reason for the `if (i < 3)` and `__builtin_unreachable()` anymore there.

Comment: I assumed the range check was intentionally there. I can think of an alternative, but it will be a hack.

Comment: The range check was only there to avoid a "control reaches end of non-void function" warning.

Comment: The offsetof array isn't a hack?? The OP doesn't seem to mind hacks, just as long as they are strictly compliant.

Comment: @JimBalter: Strictly compliant goes counter to pinning the solution to GCC.

Comment: Um, you apparently have read none of the comments under the question. I suggest that you do so. Note particularly "I would like to write standard C that compiles to efficient machine code with GCC" from the OP and "If he insists on standard-compliant code the question should say that" from me.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally you would just use `typedef double vector[3];` so all your code can then benefit, but if it is a lot of code you can just replace the struct with a union (On most systems sizeof(double)==8 so packing and padding will not be an issue, --see previous comment on arrays if you are working on some other platform )

```
#include <stddef.h> //for size_t
typedef union  __attribute__ ((packed)){
  double v[3];
  struct { double x, y, z;};
}vector;

double vector_get(vector *v, size_t i) //note the unsigned type - eliminate a conditional branch
{
if (i<3) return v->v[i];
  __builtin_unreachable(); //as long as code is not called with i>2 or i<0
}
```

This compiles to:

```
vector_get(vector*, size_t int):
    movsd   (%rdi,%rsi,8), %xmm0
    ret
```

This is roughly equivalent to  `#define vector_get(v,i) ((double*)(v))[i]` because the `__builtin_unreachable()` will generate assembly that will cause havoc if i>2

According to Agnar Fog's [compilation of assembly latency and throughput](http://www.agner.org/optimize/instruction_tables.pdf-), this is extremely fast.

<kbd><kbd>Instruction

---------------

MOVSD</kbd>
  
  

<kbd>Operands

---------------

r,r</kbd>
  
  

<kbd>μops

------

1</kbd>
  
  

<kbd>Latency

-----------

2-3</kbd>
  
  
<kbd>Reciprocal

Throughput

---------------

2</kbd>
  
  
<kbd>Instruction

Set

---------------

SSE</kbd></kbd>

This is for Pentium4 but with a single opcode, 2-3 clock cycle latency (only 2 if next instruction is in the same execution unit) and the ability to handle 1 every 2 clock cycles, there isn't much room for improvement in new CPU generations (only integer operations are faster 1 opcode ,1 cycle , 1/3 or 3 per cycle).

Of course that will only fix this one function.  You can always try something more drastic like:

```
sed -i "s/->x/[X]/g" *.h *.c #and whatever other paths/files
sed -i "s/.x/[X]/g" *.h *.c
#and so on for y and z and change your typedef to an array and an enum {X,Y,Z};
#the enum will solve your code readability concern
```

but you would probably want to leave off the -i from sed at first and grep for them so you can ensure you don't mangle something else: `grep "\->" | sed "s/->x/[0]/g"` ... just to be on the safe side (I wonder if there is a tool that can do this stuff already?)

Another alternative would be to use predefined macros.  There is no real difference in functionality; however if you try to access data outside of the range, you will get a compile time assertion (because it is not defined)

```
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_0(v,n) ((v)[0])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_1(v,n) ((v)[1])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_2(v,n) ((v)[2])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_X(v,n) ((v)[0])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_x(v,n) ((v)[0])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_Y(v,n) ((v)[1])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_y(v,n) ((v)[1])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_Z(v,n) ((v)[2])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_z(v,n) ((v)[2])
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_i(v,n) ((v)[n]) //for iterations using i (Note n can be > 2 here)
#define PREFIX_VECTOR_GET(v,n) PREFIX_VECTOR_##n(v,n)
#include <stddef.h>
static inline double vector_get(double *v,size_t i){
  return PREFIX_VECTOR_GET(v,i);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Isn't C unions (http://www.tutorialspoint.com/cprogramming/c_unions.htm) what you are searching for?

```
typedef union {
   struct { __attribute__ ((aligned (1))) double x, y, z } vector,
   double components[3];
} VectorView;


double
vector_get(const VectorView *v, size_t i)
{
    if (i<0 || i>2) __builtin_unreachable();
    v.components[i];
    // v.vector.x = ...;
}
```

(edit: Added non-portable gcc **attribute** ((aligned(1))) to fix potencial bugs commented about alignements)

Comment: Is the union actually guaranteed (by the standard) to align `x`, `y`, and `z` with `[0]`, `[1]`, and `[2]`?

Comment: @TavianBarnes It will in all known implementations. Why do you need more than that?

Comment: better use an anonymous `struct` as member.

Comment: No, the standard does not guarantee that there is no padding between the doubles inside the `struct`. This approach is just as good/evil as the cast in the question.

Comment: @cmaster: It guarantees there is no padding before the first member. Padding (an arbitrary amount) is only allowed **after** members.

Comment: @JimBalter If the code gets inlined, I can very well see a compiler using strict aliasing to do something weird.

Comment: @TavianBarnes: `struct`-layout is not undefined or unspecified, but implemenation-defined. In fact, it is part of the ABI, and all compilers use the same rules (the only one which makes sense: add minimal amount of padding to satisfy alignment requirements), even though they do not neccessarily agree on size or alignment of the basic data types. Thus, in practice `double[3]` and `struct{double a,b,c;}` are layout-compatible, and thus there is no violation of the aliasing rules.

Comment: @TavianBarnes That's irrelevant ... the addresses of the array elements are the same as the addresses of the struct fields.

Comment: C standard doesn't warranty alignement. In practice the alignment depends on the variable size and the CPU architecture. That's exactly the same in the struct and the array and will mostly work with all compilers. Otherwise you will need to manually for aligment through -non portable- compiler extensions: https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Variable-Attributes.html

Comment: @Deduplicator Are you *sure* that layout-compatible types are allowed to alias?  In my copy of the C11 draft, the relevant section 6.5.7 speaks of "compatible types" (6.2.7), which doesn't seem to be the same thing as "layout-compatible types".

Comment: @TavianBarnes: Strike out "layout", and they are.

Comment: -1: The answer takes risky assumptions. The standards says that there is not padding bytes separating elements in an array, but the same is not guaranted for struct members. It is not true, as said in a comment, that all the implementations adjust to the former case. Indeed, in general we can expect the presence of padding bytes in structs, because of allignment needs in the execution environment. I agree with your last comment, earizon but I consider that your answer teachs things that in general cases would be erroneous assumptions. Perhaps you have to repeat your last comment in your answer

Comment: @Deduplicator Haha.  If I could introduce arbitrary words into the standard, a lot of my problems would go away :)

Comment: @pablo: Not risky, but unstated. He should have added a static assertion and an explanation why it will never fire.

Comment: @Deduplicator: With "risky" I mean the possibility of trying to generalyze the `union` method to other types, different of `double`, that do not well fit allignment, as for example `mytype` in `typedef char mytype[13];`. This type has strictly 13 bytes. Padding will follow, in general, allignment in storage space, so `mytype` members in a struct will have padding in most cases. It is not good to be "teached" to do this, without an explanation of why it is supposed to work in a very particular case.